# How do I use QComboBox in relation with QVariant?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, qvariant

As I understood, `QComboBox` can hold a text (i.e. the name) and data (i.e. an object). My `QComboBox` should store `QSizeF`'s, while showing nice names. Hence I would like to do something like this:

```
void fillComboBox() {
    ui->combobox->addItem("big", QVariant(QSizeF(600,400)));   
    ui->combobox->addItem("medium", QVariant(QSizeF(300,300)));   
    ui->combobox->addItem("small", QVariant(QSizeF(100,200)));
}
```

The problem is, that `QVariant` takes a `QSizeF` by `const` reference and not by value/move. After return, the reference will therefore dangle.

What is the correct way to do that? If I've a type `MyClass`, thus a custom class and not a Q*whatever*, how would I use `QVariante` with that?

Note: of course I could create the `QSizeF` on the heap - however, I would need to take care of the memory which I try to avoid. This is eventually the reason for my question.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing problems where there are none.

1. A `const&` will keep the (in this case temporary) object it refers to alive until the reference itself goes out of scope.
2. If you look at the implementation of QVariant you'll see that it copies the value.

There's no problem here - move along.